# Resizing Cordova InAppBrowser so it appears as a window rather than covering whole screen in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I'm trying to modify the **InAppBrowser** in **Cordova for iOS** and am struggling, would anyone be able to help please?

Basically, I want the IAB to look as though it's been placed over the calling screen (leaving a visible border around the IAB that displays the screen beneath.

So far I've managed to resize the actual browsing window by changing the createViews routine, but I believe this is after the main view has been created, so it's only the browsing area thats resized.

```
- (void)createViews
{
    CGRect webViewBounds = self.view.bounds;
```

Modified the above line to create a border of 20px, eg:

```
CGRect webViewBounds = CGRectMake(20, 20, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds)-40, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds)-40);
```

Would anyone know how I can get the whole IAB to be resized to leave a border around it, rather than the grey that covers the screen beneath please?

Regards,

Andy

Comment: What do you mean by the grey border that covers the screen? Can you provide screenshots?

Comment: Any luck in finding this?

Comment: @EaswaramoorthyK, Unheilig, either of you got this to work?